# How can I change timestamps column name when using "artisan migrate"?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am struggling to change the timestamp column names which are generated by

```
php artisan migrate
```

command.

I have already made following change. When I use eloquent query builder, it can correctly generate the column name, but when I using the command above, it still generates "created_at", "updated_at" and "deleted_at". Can anyone help me out? Thanks a lot.

```
/* vendor\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php */

/**
 * The name of the "created at" column.
 *
 * @var string
 */
const CREATED_AT = 'datetime_created';

/**
 * The name of the "updated at" column.
 *
 * @var string
 */
const UPDATED_AT = 'datetime_updated';

/**
 * The name of the "deleted at" column.
 *
 * @var string
 */
const DELETED_AT = 'datetime_deleted';
```

---

```
/* vendor\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint.php */

/**
 * Indicate that the timestamp columns should be dropped.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function dropTimestamps()
{
    $this->dropColumn('datetime_created', 'datetime_updated');
}

/**
 * Add a "deleted at" timestamp for the table.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function softDeletes()
{
    $this->timestamp('datetime_deleted')->nullable();
}
/**
 * Add creation and update timestamps to the table.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function timestamps()
{
    $this->timestamp('datetime_created');

    $this->timestamp('datetime_updated');
}
/**
 * Add a "deleted at" timestamp for the table.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function softDeletes()
{
    $this->timestamp('datetime_deleted')->nullable();
}
```

P.S. I know it's not a good idea to modify the "core". If someone can tell me the best way to extend those classes I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Don't ever edit the code under the `vendor` folder. First**, it's usually (by default) not carried with your repository, so you'd lose the changes if you or anyone else ever wanted to work on another machine. **Second**, it'd be overwritten at the moment you do a `composer update`.

---

Well, that being said, let's start dealing with this "modifying the core" horror. For the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php`, simply create a base model, from which you'll be extending all your subsequent models, and overwrite the constants in it:

**app/models/BaseModel.php**

```
abstract class BaseModel extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * The name of the "created at" column.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const CREATED_AT = 'datetime_created';

    /**
     * The name of the "updated at" column.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const UPDATED_AT = 'datetime_updated';

    /**
     * The name of the "deleted at" column.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const DELETED_AT = 'datetime_deleted';

}
```

Then, for the `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint` case... Well, it gets bloody:

1. Extend `..\Schema\Blueprint`, overwriting the methods you mentioned.
2. Extend `..\Schema\Builder`, overwriting `createBlueprint` method to use your new `Blueprint` class.

   - Also extend `..\Schema\MySqlBuilder` to extend from your new `Builder` class.
3. Extend `..\Connection`, overwriting  `getSchemaBuilder` method to use your new `Builder` class.

   - Also extend `..\MySqlConnection`, `..\PostgresConnection`, `..\SqlServerConnection` and `..\SQLiteConnection` to extend from your new `Connection` class.
   - **Note:** `..\MySqlConnection` also needs to have its `getSchemaBuilder` method extended to use your new `MySqlBuilder` class.
4. Extend `..\ConnectionFactory`, overwriting `createConnection` method to use your extended `Connection` classes.
5. Create a `ServiceProvider` to register your new `ConnectionFactory` class as the new `db.factory` component, and add it on your `app/config/app.php` file, under `providers`.

So, after half an hour digging through Laravel's source code to figure that out, I came to the conclusion that it would **probably** be easier to simply do the following on your migrations:

```
$table->timestamp(BaseModel::CREATED_AT);
$table->timestamp(BaseModel::UPDATED_AT);
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for your reply! I really appreciate your help. Since I finished my work at office about 8 hours ago, I probably only can give it a try tomorrow at my home PC.